# Simultaneous square values of binary quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $f_1, \cdots f_k$ be binary quadratic forms with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients, such that no two of them share a common linear factor. I want to count the number of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that

$$\displaystyle f_j(x,y) \text{ is a square for } 1 \leq j \leq k.$$

Clearly, if any of the $f_j$'s is irreducible and not in the principal genus then the number of solutions will be zero, since there is a local obstruction. If $k \geq 3$ then the number of solutions will be finite, since any solution corresponds to a rational point on the hyperelliptic curve defined by

$$\displaystyle (f_1 \cdots f_k)(x,y) = v^2$$

which will have genus at least two when $k \geq 3$ (since the binary form on the left hand side will have degree at least six and no repeated linear factors). When $k = 2$ it is possible for there to be infinitely many solutions: indeed, looking at $f_1(x,y) = u^2$ say we can parametrize the points by a triple of binary quadratic forms $(g_{1,1}, g_{1,2}, g_{1,3})$, then substuting $x = g_{1,1}(a,b), y = g_{1,2}(a,b)$ into $f_2(x,y) = v^2$ gives a genus one curve $f_2(g_{1,1}, g_{1,2}) = F(a,b) = v^2$. If this curve has positive rank then the number of solutions will be infinite.

Is it possible to prove that when $k \geq 3$ that the number of solutions will be finite, without invoking either Siegel or Faltings' theorem applied to the hyperelliptic curve above? If so, does such an approach provide an effective way to bound the number of solutions?